# In a dataframe column of ints, replace every repeated occurence of n to floats between n and n+1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a df with a column `a` that looks like so:

```
a
-
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
2
4
4
5
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to "de-duplicate" the values by converting them to intermediate floats. So the expected output can be either of the two shown below

```
a          a
-          -
1          1
2.25       2
2.5        2.33333
3.2        3
3.4        3.25
3.6        3.5
3.8        3.75
2.75       2.66666
4.33333    4
4.66666    4.5
5          5
```

The only thing I can think of is to do a groupby on `a` and put an np.linspace from 0 to n, where n is the value of `a` for that group. But I think this is inefficient. Are there better, faster ways to do this? Thanks!

Comment: there's also the same error on SO when (re)editing any post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
g = df.groupby('a')['a']
s = g.transform('size')
df['out'] = np.where(s>1, df['a']+g.cumcount().add(1)/s.add(1), s)
```

Second method:

```
g = df.groupby('a')['a']
df['out2'] = df['a']+g.cumcount()/g.transform('size')
```

Output:

```
    a       out      out2
0   1  1.000000  1.000000
1   2  2.250000  2.000000
2   2  2.500000  2.333333
3   3  3.200000  3.000000
4   3  3.400000  3.250000
5   3  3.600000  3.500000
6   3  3.800000  3.750000
7   2  2.750000  2.666667
8   4  4.333333  4.000000
9   4  4.666667  4.500000
10  5  1.000000  5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy-linspace) to get evenly spaced numbers:

```py
df["a_new"] = df.groupby("a", sort=False, group_keys=False)["a"].transform(
    lambda s: np.linspace(0, 1, len(s), endpoint=False) + s.iat[0]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    a     a_new
0   1  1.000000
1   2  2.000000
2   2  2.333333
3   3  3.000000
4   3  3.250000
5   3  3.500000
6   3  3.750000
7   2  2.666667
8   4  4.000000
9   4  4.500000
10  5  5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying uniform distribution ([`np.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)) only for repeated sequences:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
(df.groupby('a')['a'].transform(lambda x: rng.uniform(x.name, x.name+1, x.size)
                                if x.size > 1 else x))
```

---

```
0     1.000000
1     2.328058
2     2.570871
3     3.116998
4     3.887849
5     3.353023
6     3.127169
7     2.810340
8     4.006301
9     4.435186
10    5.000000
```